# How to find which program is reading a file?

Tags: malware

I tried delete some file but windows 8.1 reported that access is denied, which other program might read that file, but I don't run any. So it is maybe a harmful program.

How can I find out which program is holding that file?

Comment: I do hope this group won't fall into the problems some other SE groups do. That of downvoting without make clear what the problem is. Please don't assume that new users yet understand the rules!

Comment: This question is getting downvoted (not by me) because it is off topic in Information Security. Please delete this question and ask it instead in the SuperUser group.

Comment: What file are you trying to delete and from what location? Have you tried in Safe Mode? Why did you use the Malware tag? Did a malware scan confirm this is the reason you can't delete the file?

Answer (score 3):

There is a program called Process Monitor by sysinternals it will tell you what program did what. Here is the link

```
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)** will show you which process has a file locked.

Click the icon that looks like a pair of Binoculars (or press CTRL-F)

Type the name of the file you are trying to delete.

You will then see which process has the file locked.